# Why is sys.path initialized differently during startup than when run from bash, for Python embedded in Apache

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using Python embedded in Apache using modwsgi, and I am finding that the sys.path does not get initialized correctly when Apache is started from the rc2.d startup folder than when run from the shell.

The versions:
Ubuntu Lucid 10.04
Apache 2.2
Python 2.6
mod_wsgi 3.3

Firstly, I am testing the initialization using this app:

```
import sys   
import os   
def application(environ, start_response):   
    status = '200 OK'   
    output = ['version %s\n'%sys.version]   
    output.append('sys.prefix = %s \n' % repr(sys.prefix))   
    output.append('sys.exec_prefix = %s \n' % repr(sys.exec_prefix))  
    output.append('sys.path = %s \n' % repr(sys.path))  
    output.append('env.PYTHONHOME = %s\n' % repr(os.environ.get('PYTHONHOME')))
    output.append('env.PATH = %s\n' % repr(os.environ.get('PATH')))
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(sum([len(o) for o in output])))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return output
```

When apache2 is started from bash, via 'sudo apache2ctl start', or 'sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start', it initializes correctly, and the app above shows:

```
version 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 14:15:55) 
[GCC 4.4.3]
sys.prefix = '/usr' 
sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local' 
sys.path = ['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/WebOb-1.0.7-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twiddler-0.9.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/elementtree-1.2.7_20070827_preview-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages'] 
env.PYTHONHOME = '/usr:/usr/local'
env.PATH = '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin'
```

When apache2 is started from /etc/rc2.d during boot, it does not initialize correctly, and the app shows:

```
version 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 14:15:55) 
[GCC 4.4.3]
sys.prefix = '/usr' 
sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local' 
sys.path = ['/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload'] 
env.PYTHONHOME = '/usr:/usr/local'
env.PATH = '/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin'
```

Critical directories are not found, including dist-packages.

I have tried moving the apache script earlier and later in the startup sequence, and gotten uniformly bad results.  Loading apache last in the startup gets the dysfunctional sys.path; loading it from the shell, immediately afterward, loads correctly.

The question, again, is why would the sys.path initialize differently run as a startup process than run from the shell?

Follow-up:

site.py is not being run by Python's initialization.  Now I am seeing mod_wsgi errors "unable to import 'site' module".  The errors started appearing after providing a WSGIPythonPath value in Apach2.conf, though the sys.path symptoms have been there all along.

There is something about the combination of chrooting Apache and starting from rc#.d scripts that is breaking Python's site.py loading.

Launching Apache from the shell, via sudo, or sudo -i, from a brand new account, works fine.

Comment: What is the value of `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in both scenarios?

Comment: This sounds like an Ubuntu issue, not a Python or httpd issue.

Comment: @sarnold No PYTHONPATH env variable used.  I could use it, but it would have to be long and messy.

Comment: Why are you setting PYTHONHOME environment variable in the first place as you shouldn't need to? You also want to avoid relying on PYTHONPATH being set in your user account as well so don't go off trying to set it for Apache now. Use WSGIPythonPath or python-path option to WSGIDaemonProcess as appropriate for whether using mod_wsgi embedded mode or daemon mode. That or set sys.path in your WSGI script. If you really needed to set PYTHONHOME, which I doubt very much, then the directive in Apache is WSGIPythonHome.

Answer (score 0):

You're running as a different user. Bash (and your other login scripts) set some of your path variables when you run as your standard user that may not get set when running as the apache user on startup.

Apache is initializing correctly. You just need to be explicit about which paths you want to include, if you need them.

It's the same reason you often need to be more explicit when running cron jobs.

When you use sudo to become that user, part of your existing environment persist, including your your python path variables. You need to use the -i option with sudo to simulate what happens when the root user initially logs in and runs apache.

http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.8.0/sudo.man.html#i_command

Comment: I believe the user is root in both cases.

Comment: @pduel, it depends upon how `sudo` was invoked -- `sudo -i` will scrub the environment, `sudo -s` will perform only whatever environment scrubbing has been configured via `env_reset` in `sudoers(5)`. So a standard user `/home/pduel/.bashrc`-set `PYTHONPATH` will persist into `sudo -s` environment, but will be scrubbed out of a `sudo -i` environment.

Comment: @sarnold even sudo -i doesn't seem to scrub the PATH.  I added a complete environment dump to my application, and find that the PATH is fuller on the success cases than the fail cases; it is time to experiment with PYTHONPATH.